# How to get value in main view from partial view loaded with ajax call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am working on MVC project in which I have Main view and in which I am loading partial view using ajax call by passing the reference number.
It works like this . I place order by entering reference number, when  I add reference number it check if any order already exists against that reference number in database by ajax call in controller on change event. If any order exists against that reference table loads in partial view .
               Now what I really want is  value of the partial view to be load in main view so that I can update the existing order.Hope u can understand my question below is my code:

```
  <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.reference, new { placeholder = "Reference Number", required = "required", @class = "form-control form-group-margin" })
            </div>
<div id="loadpartial"></div>




  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#reference").on("change", function () {
        var refer = $("#reference").val();
        $.post("/CRUD/CheckifOrderExists=" + refer, function (data) {
            $("#GetNumber").html(data);

        });
    });
});
```

Now is Partial view:

```
<table id="dtable" class="table-primary table-responsive col-md-7">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td id="orderHead">
                Description
            </td>
            <td id="orderHead">
                Country Name
            </td>
            <td id="orderHead">
                City Name
            </td>
            <td id="orderHead">
                Quantity
            </td>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center">
                    @item.description
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:center">
                    @did.CountryName
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:center">
                    @itemd.cityName
```

```
                      @item.quantity
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>


}
```

I want to load the table from partial view in the main view new div so that I can add more order under existing reference number .

I know I will go like each loop on data after ajax call but dnt know how .

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX get method to fetch the data from view and append it in the div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#reference").on("change", function () {
        var refer = $("#reference").val();
        $.post("/CRUD/CheckifOrderExists=" + refer, function (data) {
            $("#GetNumber").html(data);
            $.get("/partial_view_route", function (data) {
              $("#loadpartial").append(data);
            });    

        });
    });
});
```

Create a get route in your router file and replace that route in inner AJAX.